# Add a directory to git but not the conent

Tags: git, directory

I have folder1 and folder 2 under git root folder

```
gitroot/  
  folder1  
    content...  
  folder2  
    content...
```

I want to add **folder1** and **folder2** to git but don't want to add their content.

I have tried

```
!folder1
folder1/**
!folder2
folder2/**
```

which doesn't seem to work. Please advise.

Comment: git doesn't see folders at all. It only tracks content. Why do you *think* you need to track folders?

Comment: for providing a directory structure in repo. I think, then I need to provide a dummy file.  anyways, thanks for the hint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+empty+directory

Answer (score 0):

Git does not track directories, so you have to rely on a common used trick:

1. Exclude the folder by `.gitignore`.
2. Add an empty file `.gitkeep` into the folder.
3. Force adding the above file by `git add -f`.

Comment: if you need to ignore all of the directory's content, you may as well version a single `echo "*" > dir/.gitignore` file in the directory,

Comment: The user asked to track the directory, but not the content, so the solution is the one I provided.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca that works fine too. and your answer as well. Found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-a-blank-directory-to-a-git-repository

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8418403/4669744 here is why I am not going with your solution for now. As other solution fits best to my case. Thnx anyways.

Comment: The two solutions are identical. ;)